# What would be the best method to save message conversations in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

**Note:** I have already read all the articles and questions about chat and messages on this site. So donot try to provide me links, they are just helping out users with `MySql` but I am using `SQL CE` Note the **CE** in it. And I know this aint a code generating site I respect the terms of use of this site. But I got no choice! I have to go for a suggestion.

**What I want:** I want to have a messages table in my database. What I want is that it should save the messages and then I would get the messages from it. It should save `Time`, `Message`, `Sender` and `Recipient` and finally `Seen` column.

**What I am having:** The database table that I am having contains these columns. But the issue is that I want these:

1. Distinct sender and recipient. More like a threaded conversation.
2. Ordered by Time. So that the latest one comes up.
3. Rest will be accessed by a query inside the block. So that's not an issue like the Profile Picture, UserId, UserName and others

What I was able to create is this:

[image: message]

You can see that I did create the table. That saved the chats! But the point to note here is that I have used this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Recipient FROM Messages WHERE Sender =2 OR Recipient =2
```

And I was able to get the results like a Thread, but they were not ordered. They won't be ordered unless I select time too. But selecting the TIME will remove the functionality of `DISTINCT`.

Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated. I just don't know how to create a threaded view and order it by Time! Remember I am using **SQL Server CE** so the tricks you can do on **SQL Server** won't work here. So provide me with a code that would select these all and would help me out too. I am stuck on this one!

Thanks in advance for your precious time guys, Cheers!

Comment: Break the table into two, parent & child, parent will have Conversation header, sender, receiver and the child will have conversion content belongs to sender and receiver with data timestamp.

So when you retrieve from Parent you get the result what you want.

Another which I am not recommending is to put as XML in form of Ntext or binary if you don't what to further query the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to order by timestamp without including it in the select.

try just adding `ORDER BY TIME DESC` to your query

Comment: Do you really I did not try that? I have tried this. But no greatness! It givees error

Comment: Honestly I can not know what you have tried unless you tell me :) What error please?

Comment: I have tried `DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`. And more over everything that is allowed in `Sql Ce`.